# Eigenvectors Shared By Two Matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Background:**

- $\bf{x}$ is an eigenvector of matrix $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$.
- $M = 7I -2A + A^2$

  - Where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A^2 = AA$

**Question:**

How do we know that $\bf{x}$ is also an eigenvector of the matrix $M$? What are the eigenvalues that go with this matrix? Is there a formula that relates the eigenvalues to the operations on $A$ that form $M$?

This relation seems arbitrary, yet I've checked (with *Mathematica*) it's true for a variety of matrices...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's calculate $M\mathbf x$ and see what happens:
$$M\mathbf x=(7I-2A+A^2)\mathbf x=7\mathbf x-2A\mathbf x+A^2\mathbf x=7\mathbf x-2\lambda\mathbf x+\lambda^2\mathbf x=(7-2\lambda+\lambda^2)\mathbf x$$
where we used the fact that $A^2\mathbf x=A(A\mathbf x)=A(\lambda\mathbf x)=\lambda A\mathbf x=\lambda^2\mathbf x$. Hence $\mathbf x$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with corresponding eigenvalue $7-2\lambda+\lambda^2$.

Perhaps unsurprisingly, this generalizes as follows: if $P(\lambda)$ is a polynomial and $M=P(A)$, then $\mathbf x$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $P(\lambda)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that $M\mathbf x=\mu\mathbf x$ for some scalar $\mu$, this is the definition of eigenvector.

$$M\mathbf x=(7I-2A+A^2)\mathbf x=7I\mathbf x-2A\mathbf x+A^2\mathbf x=7\mathbf x-2\lambda\mathbf x+A\lambda\mathbf x=7\mathbf x-2\lambda\mathbf x+\lambda^2\mathbf x=...$$

Now finish it up.